# Clarification on the `.size()` of multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

Say I have a some code like:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long int> > > pooHistory;
pooHistory pHist (1, vector<vector<long int>>(1, vector<long int>(1,0)));
```

that kept track of, for example:

- The number of dogs
- The number of times each dog defecates
- The position of each defecation.

Would `pHist.size()` be the number of dogs?
Would `pHist[1].size()` be the number of times the first dog defecated?
Would `pHist[1][1].size()` be the size of said defecation? (small to OHMYGOD!) ... (Kidding)

Actually,would `pHist[1][1].size()` be the dimensions of the coordinate axis used to record the position of the first defecation?

Comment: Yes, except that the first element has index 0, not 1.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I had forgotten about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Yes. No. Yes.
(Bonus text here.)

Comment: (Modulo what Marc said.)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure and I figured I'd ask some experts.